# How to remove error in 2-d array declaration using pointers?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, dereference

If I declare a two dimensional array as

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() { int c=5;int r=6;
    int **a=(int **) malloc (c*sizeof(int *));
    int i,j;
    for (i=0;i<c;i++){
        *(a+i)=(int *) malloc (r*sizeof (int));
    }
}
```

The above program works successfully.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() { int c=5;int r=6;
    int **a;
     **a=(int **) malloc (c*sizeof (int *));
    int i,j;
    for (i=0;i<c;i++){
        *(a+i)=(int *) malloc (r*sizeof (int));
    }
}
```

But the compiler shows an error in the above program.

Why so? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the mentioned error ?

Comment: The second one should be `a=(int **) malloc(c*sizeof (int *));`, or preferably `a=malloc(c*sizeof(*a));`.

Comment: Also [don't cast the return value of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc), please.

Comment: The asterisks in here `int **a;` and in here `**a =` are not the same.

Comment: To break down the original `int **a = (int **)malloc(c * sizeof(int *));`, `int **a = ...` declares the type of `a` to be `int **` and `... a=(int **)malloc(...);` initializes `a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declared a pointer of the type `int **` that is not initialized and has an indeterminate value.

```
int **a;
```

Then in the next statement you are dereferencing the pointer two times

```
 **a=(int **) malloc (c*sizeof (int *));
```

The expression `**a` has the type `int` while the right hand side expression has the type `int **`.

So the compiler issues a message that the operands have different types.

Moreover dereferencing an uninitialized pointer results in undefined behavior if such a program will be run.

You should at least write

```
 a=(int **) malloc (c*sizeof (int *));
```

Pay attention to that if in the first program the variable `r` means rows and the variable `c` means columns then you should allocate arrays by rows that is the program should look like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() { int c=5;int r=6;
    int **a=(int **) malloc (r*sizeof(int *));
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<r;i++){
        *(a+i)=(int *) malloc (c*sizeof (int));
    }
}
```

Otherwise the expression `a[i]` will yield a column instead of a row.

After you will allocate arrays as shown above then the expression `**a` is equivalent to the expression `a[0][0]` and will yield the object of the type `int` that is stored in the first column of the first row.